# Will I really have to spend $2000 for an MBox 2 Pro and DV toolkit so that I can learn it while being able to read OMFs?

Tags: pro-tools, gear, budget, low-budget

Hi Everyone...

But I'd really really like to know whether I need to fork out close to $2000 to have a decent interface, Pro Tools and the ability to import OMFs etc?

Buying an Mbox 2 Pro is affordable enough, but, to import OMFs, do ABSO-POSA_LUTELY need to buy this darned DV Toolkit??!!

Does anybody have a work around?

I do most of my sound design in Ableton Live, and when I need to deal with OMFs, I import them into Soundtrack Pro 2(which handles OMFs) and then bring my sounds in there...
That also helps when edits are changed etc.

What do you guy do..? I'm referring to those of us not using ProTools, in any way shape or form.

I'm very very keen on buying ProTools, and would like to get a Proper interface with it. The Mbox 2 seems a good bet.

Advice anyone?

(Is this a stupid question?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need to import OMF's, look on eBay for a Digitranslator 2 license.  Should be around $150.  Like the other guys said, you get a lot more than just OMF support with DV Toolkit.  It is a worthy investment if you are going with a non-HD Pro Tools rig.

Answer (score 5):

DV Toolkit has other valuable features besides omf import...  A cheap workaround to deal with omfs is that you could always import the omf into soundtrack pro,  consolidate each track, and then import into pro tools and line up the heads of the files.

Comment: the whole point of getting an OMF is to access the handles on each cut.... you wouldn't want to be consolidating the tracks

Answer (score 5):

The new Pro Tools 9 has OMF import/export as standard now.

Answer (score 3):

Once upon a time there was a free program called Omf Tool, but i think that's only compatible with Mac OS 9 or earlier. As far as i know it hasn't been updated, and can only save to Pro Tools v 4 or 5 sessions. It was also a little buggy for me at times.

You can buy DigiTranslator for $500 by itself, but that won't get you the timecode and mixing functions that ($1300) DV Toolkit would. It seems that most other software comes with omf capability, but unfortunately Digidesign make you pay. I got mine from the Digi training and education store for virtually half price, but i had to do a Pro Tools course first, and they cost quite a bit.

Hopefully someone else has some good advice for you.

Best of luck!

Comment: Update: The Digi training and education store is no more; ever since Avid bought them. I hesitate to use emoticons around professionals, but :-(

Answer (score 3):

You could also check out Nuendo, I got my nuendo on ebay, for like 300 bucks, it was nuendo 2, then upgraded, This also opens up the doors to many diff. IO

Answer (score 2):

I have MBox2 & Digitranslator which performs the OMF task. I did a Pro Tools course some time ago and chose Digitranslator as my free plug in - not sure what it would cost otherwise. I really recommend doing a course as it entitles you to quite hefty discounts on Avid and Pro Tools products (the production toolkits are about 50% cheaper) and help the course to pay for itself.

Answer (score 2):

Hey All,

Thank you all fir the invaluable input.
What I will do is the following:

I will buy an MBox2 Pro Factory, save for a PT course, and then try and get a discount on DV toolkit or at least DigiTranslator when/if I can.
I think i will be able to get the best value for money then. And a course in something as complex as PT will be invaluable to fellow like myself.

Thank you to all of you again.
This site is amazing. I have really seen the quality of my work and the depth of consideration in my approach improve inthe few months I have been a member here.

Cheers, 
Kurt

Comment: @Kurt - I've taken the Pro Tools courses, and they're not bad. The certification process is stupid, for lack of a better word, if you're thinking of going that route. The online testing is all screwed up and doesn't work; mostly miswording that leaves multiple correct answers, or none at all (at least the last time I took them they were). The first course follows the book they've released word for word. So, you'd probably be better off just buying that and saving the money you would have spent on that course for DV Toolkit. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: The best Pro Tools courses out there is just using it from day to day production and reading the manual. Half those courses are just reading the manual and doing stuff - save the 350$ an hour and read the manual and do some projects and get to know it. I promise you the courses and certification is not worth it. I would dare say I could go head to head against any Pro Tools instructor out there and rip him to shreds (no offense, but just to prove the point). Sorry if I offended any Pro Tools instructors...

Comment: @Ryan - pretty much agree with you there....and the courses I took were the Digidesign approved course. Like I said they're really not bad (depends on the instructor), but skip the whole certification thing. Really glad work paid for those classes and I didn't shell out the cash myself.

Answer (score 1):

Scan the audio equipment websites.  You can find "educational" versions of most mbox's as well as dvtoolkit.  These versions are fully functional, and will cost you half the price.

Answer (score 0):

You can currently purchase the mbox 2 mini for £131 with PT 8 LE, you can then crossgrade to 9 for £180, which has OMF conversion.